# Parsing option and optgroup in XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml file that defines form fields. In the case of a list with optgroups, my xml would contain something like

```
<field
    name="expertise"
    type="multilist"
    label="Area of Expertise"
>
    <option value="Disaster Management">Disaster Management </option>
    <option value="Energy Security">Energy Security </option>
    <optgroup label="Environment">
        <option value="Climate">Climate </option>
        <option value="Resource Security">Resource Security </option>
    </optgroup>
</field>
```

I am trying to loop through nodes such as

```
foreach ($feed->fieldset[1]->field[$j]->children() as $c):
    foreach($c->attributes() as $key => $value):
        echo '<'.$c->getName().' '.$key.'="'.$value.'">'.$c.'</'.$c->getName().'><br>';
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

I know, probably doesn't make sense for the value to equal the label, but I'll worry about that later.

For now, I am trying to figure out how to loop through both the options and the options within an optgroup. Above loop is not showing the optgroup's options (as expected). Seems I probably have to do some recursion, but was wondering if there are better ways you might recommend, such as existing php xml functions that handle what I am trying to do (so far I have not found anything).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use XML parser

```
<?php
$myXMLData = '<field
name="expertise"
type="multilist"
label="Area of Expertise">
<option value="Disaster Management">Disaster Management </option>
<option value="Energy Security">Energy Security </option>
<optgroup label="Environment">
    <option value="Climate">Climate </option>
    <option value="Resource Security">Resource Security </option>
</optgroup>
</field>';

 $xml=simplexml_load_string($myXMLData);

 print_r($xml);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it to work like so. The main thing was I needed to be able to mark as selected options that were previously selected.

```
$feed= simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
foreach ($feed->fieldset[1]->field[$ind]->children() as $c):
   if ($c->getName() == 'option'):
      $selected = (in_array($c->attributes()->value, (array)$val)) ? ' selected' : '';
   $ctrl.= '<option value = '.'"'.$c->attributes()->value.'"'.$selected.'>'.$c.'</option><br>';
   elseif ($c->getName() == 'optgroup'): 
      $ctrl.= '<optgroup label = '.'"'.$c->attributes()->label.'"><br>';
      foreach ($c as $c2):
           $selected = (in_array($c2->attributes()->value, (array)$val)) ? ' selected' : '';
           $ctrl.= '<option value = '.'"'.$c2->attributes()->value.'"'.$selected.'>'.$c2.'</option><br>';    
      endforeach;
      $ctrl.= '</optgroup><br>';
   endif;
endforeach;
```